# How to use our custom code(which converts json into csv) into Google cloud dataflow?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

I have my own code to convert json into csv..i need to put this code in gcp and develop a dataflow job(which will read json from cloud storage and convert into csv and again placed into cloud storage)

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions())
class to_csv(beam.DoFn): 
    def process(self,f):
        columns_list = ["col1",]
        with open(f,"r") as f1:
            dd= ast.literal_eval(f1.readlines()[0])
            for each in dd['data']:
                for ELEMENT in each["values"]:
                    for KEY,VALUE in ELEMENT.items():

                        if KEY=="value" and type(VALUE)==dict:
                            columns_list.extend(VALUE.keys())
        new_col_list = list(set(columns_list))
        sample = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_col_list)

    #Adding values to the table structure

        for each in range(len(dd['data'])):
            empty_dict = {}
            empty_dict["col1"] = dd['data'][each]["id"]
            ["description"]


            for ELEMENT in dd['data'][each]["values"]:
                for KEY,VALUE in ELEMENT.items():
                    if KEY=="value":
                        if type(VALUE)==int:
                            empty_dict["value"]=VALUE
                        elif type(VALUE)==dict:
                            temp_df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(VALUE,orient="index").T
                            for ind in temp_df.columns:
                                empty_dict[ind] = temp_df[ind][0]       
                    elif KEY=="end_time":
                        end_time_lis = VALUE
            empty_dict["end_time"] = end_time_lis

            sample = sample.append(empty_dict,ignore_index=True)



parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__,formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
result =p.run()
#loading the data from the source file
data_from_source = (p | 'ReadMyFile' >> ReadFromText("sourcepath"))
data_from_source | 'Convert To Csv' >> beam.ParDo(to_csv())| 'exportresult'>>WriteToText('outputpath')
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by writing on Google Cloud Function.

Google Function is serverless and you need to pay (if not free subscription) only for the duration this function executes.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-console

Answer (score 0):

The Beam TextIO supports reading and writing from GCS. So to read from GCS, replace 'ReadFromText("sourcepath")' with 'ReadFromText("gs://my-bucket/sourcepath")'.

Writing is a little more difficult if you want a single file. You can replace "WriteToText('outputpath')" with "WriteToText('gs://my-bucket/outprefix')", and it will write one file per shard gs://my-bucket/outprefix-0001-of-00262. Cloud Functions is one option to merge the output files if you need a single file output.